# Problema Por El Contexto

Tags: android-studio

Tengo un ListView personalizado y un botón que al presionarlo guarda un dato, en este botón utilizo "SharedPreferences" las preferencias compartidas, el problema es que el adaptador(Codigo Java) es así:

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter{
```

Entonces no puedo llamar el método SharedPreferences para guardar los datos entonces lo que hice cree un archivo Java llamado 'datos.java' y crear la función 'GuardarDatos' para guardar los datos que seria así:

```
 public  void GuardarDatos(String posicion, boolean valor)
{

    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("settingAlarmas", this.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(posicion, valor); //ID - ESTADO
    editor.apply();
}
```

La funcion 'GuardarDatos' esta siendo llama desde el adaptador de esta forma:

```
Datos d = new Datos();
d.GuardarDatos("valor",true); //ID- Y Valor
```

El problema es por el **contexto** en el cual es llamado por el `this` en el cual este solo sirve para la actividad actual pero **Yo no se que contexto utilizar para que funcione la aplicacion** porque están siendo llamado otros metodos de otras clases para hacer funcionar el adaptador personalizado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.-Desde tu actividad cuando creas el Adaptador pasa el contexto como parámetro asi `Adaptador miAdaptador = new Adaptador(this);` luego en la clase Adaptador crea un atributo de tipo `Context` para que lo puedas usar en toda la clase.

2.-Añade el contexto como parámetro a tu método GuardarDatos asi:

```
public  void GuardarDatos(Context context, String posicion, boolean valor) {}
```

3.-dentro del método llama al modo: `context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

4.- Pasa el contexto cuando llamas al método GuardarDatos:

```
Datos d = new Datos();
d.GuardarDatos(contexto, "valor",true);
```

El **contexto** es el que le pasas desde la actividad al Adaptador. (`new Adaptador(this)`) y que debería estar como atributo en la clase Adaptador.

Answer (score 0):

Hola perdona la respuesta incompleta no he tocado Android en mucho tiempo. Así puedes pasar el contexto, pues me ha funcionado perfecto en mis apps.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("settingAlarmas", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Sin embargo también podrias usar getApplicationContext() pues entiendo necesitas el contexto no en la actividad sino en la aplicación.